# Get Android IMEI without starting onCreate

Tags: android

I want to get my Device IMEI without calling onCreate method in my class:

```
public class EM extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper>
{
    public void CreateMessage(Exception e, String className)
    {
        try
        {    
            TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String deviceid = manager.getDeviceId();    
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but I keep on getting this error: "System services not available to Activities before onCreate()". Is there any way to get IMEI without calling OnCreate?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't do it after `onCreate`?

Comment: if I create onCreate method It just ignores it

Comment: How do you start the activity? `oCreate` is the first method called by Android when an activity is started.

Comment: new EM().CreateMessage(e, getLocalClassName());

Comment: don't instantiate an `Activity` yourself, let the system do it. If you want to start an activity use `startActivity(intent)`.